# SQL query with multiple conditions and null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get as result a table with two columns

- first 'ship' containing names of all ships
- second 'Numberofbattles' when the outcome is 'damaged'

and the ships that are not damaged to have 0 in second column.

I got this query below but the ships with zeroes are missing...
how can I add them?

```sql
SELECT Outcomes.Ship, COUNT(battles.name) AS NumberOfbattles 
FROM outcomes
LEFT JOIN Battles ON Outcomes.battle = battles.name
WHERE result LIKE 'damaged'
GROUP BY Ship;
```

Also for the same DB.

I need a query that can get the ships that were 'damaged' and later won in another battle

(assuming the battles table have only names and date)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause turns the outer join into an inner join:

```
SELECT o.Ship, COUNT(b.name) AS NumberOfbattles
FROM outcomes o LEFT JOIN
     Battles b
     ON o.battle = b.name AND b.result like 'damaged'
GROUP BY o.Ship;
```

Why?  Non-matched results are `NULL` and your `WHERE` filters them out.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know that about the "where" clause very helpful and fast response :)